# Animate Grid Margin on MainForm from Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a User Control (Menu.xaml) on a Parent Window( Dashboard) with a grid name="page".
 I also have a button ( ButtonOpenMenu) on the User Control and I want to change the Margin property of the grid(page) on the main form.

so basically

On the UserControl code behind

```
   public void ButtonOpenMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         //  change margin of grid on Parent Wndow(Dashboard)

ThicknessAnimation grdanimation =  new ThicknessAnimation(new thickness(0), new Thickness(200, 0, 0, 0),
       new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
Dashboard db = new Dashbaord();

        db.page.BeginAnimation(Border.MarginProperty, anima);


        }
```

Any Help?

Comment: When you call `Dashboard db = new Dashbaord();` you are creating a new Dashboard, which is obviously not the one that already exists. Try `db = (Dashboard)Application.Current.MainWindow;`

Comment: If the Grid in the Dashboard is the direct parent element of the UserControl, you may also try `Parent.BeginAnimation(...)`

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution to my question.

so in my Menu.xaml (Usercontrol)  I  created a static Event

```
// static
public static event EventHandler AnimateButtonClicked;

  // button click event
public void Animatebutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AnimateButtonClicked(this, e);
    }
```

then in the MainWindow (Dashboard) . I created a method (DoAnimate) that gets fired when the button(Animatebutton) on my usercontrol is clicked.

```
    Dashboard.xaml

    private void DoAnimate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        ThicknessAnimation anima =
        new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0), new Thickness(150, 0, 0, 0),
        new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
        anima.From = new Thickness(150, 0, 0, 0);
        anima.To = new Thickness(100, 0, 0, 0);
        anima.AutoReverse = false;

        // page is the name of the grid that gets animated.
        page.BeginAnimation(Border.MarginProperty, anima);
    }

 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Menu.AnimateButtonClicked += new EventHandler(DoAnimate);

    }
```

Comment: The AnimateButtonClicked event must not be static. You shoukld instead assign the `x:Name` of the Menu like `x:Name="menu"`, and then attach the handler like `menu.AnimateButtonClicked += DoAnimate;`

Comment: I tired using the x name, but it keeps giving me error: An object reference is required for the non static field, method or property  "menu.AnimateButtonClicked"